# Will I blow up my LCR Meter?

Tags: measurement, capacitance, lcr

I have a situation where I need to measure a capacitor connected to a live circuit like the image shows. I'm considering a LCR meter because we also have to measure both capacitance and resistance of the entire circuit.

The circuit will be powered by red and black terminals and the measurement is done by red and blue terminals. We need the relay to be opened and that's why we need to apply mains (AC) voltage to it's coil.

Is there a way to measure it with a LCR Meter? Any grounding trick maybe?

[image: lcr circuit I need to measure]

Comment: Yes you will...

Answer (score 2):

> I have a situation where I need to measure a capacitor connected to a live circuit ... Is there a way to measure it with a LCR Meter? Any grounding trick maybe?

No.

The LCR meter will output a test current at low voltage to the devices under test. This will generally be in the order of a volt or two. The live circuit will likely destroy the test meter.

Answer (score 2):

Since the AC supply is only operating the coil of the relay, and isn't imposed on the circuit you are trying to measure, it should be possible. Obviously, there's a common point between the circuit you are measuring and the meter connection, so there's the possibility of putting line voltage on the meter connection. it wouldn't bother a portable battery-powered LCR meter in terms of it taking a valid measurement, but the risk to the operator pushing the buttons can't be ignored.

Ensuring that the common point is on the neutral side of the supply will eliminate this risk - if you're in a location where the singe phase supply is grounded on one side. If you aren't, or you're not sure, you'd need an isolating transformer - which I use all the time in my lab, since it ensures that there's no significant ground fault current from touching any singe point on the live circuit - either through the operator, or through any test equipment that has a path to ground, which includes my oscilloscopes.

Comment: We're considering both the transformer to isolate the DUT and the common point as a neutral point, but the meter is a bench instrument and we will control it remotely.